# OOP PHP built price returns nothing

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to calculate a price by building it up out of product components using OOP PHP. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

In my opinion, I don't need to call the functions into the constructor directly, right?

Can someone give me some tips how I can make this work correctly?

**Price Class:**

```
class Price
{

    public $width;
    public $height;
    public $glasstype;
    public $color;
    protected $squares;
    private $_price = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setSquareMeters();
        $this->glasstypePrice();    
        $this->colorPrice();
        $this->sumPrice();
    }

    // Set millimeters to square meters 
    protected function setSquareMeters()
    {
        $this->squares = $this->width * $this->height / 1000000;
    }

    // Set glasstype price 
    protected function glasstypePrice()
    {
        switch( $this->glasstype )
        {
            case '1' :
                $this->_price['glass'] = $this->squares * 50;
                break;
            case '2' :  
                $this->_price['glass'] = $this->squares * 70;
                break;
        }
    }

    // Set color price
    protected function colorPrice()
    {
        if( $this->color != 'none' )
        {
            $this->_price['color'] = 40 * $this->squares;   
        }
    }

    // Sum price array up   
    protected function sumPrice()
    {
        $this->_price = array_sum( $this->_price ); 
    }

    // Get price
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->_price;   
    }

}
```

**Initiating the object and echo out the price:**

```
$price = new Price();

$price->width = 800;
$price->height = 930;
$price->glasstype = 1;
$price->color = 2;

echo $price->getPrice();
```

Comment: When the constructor calls `$this->setSquareMeters();` and neither `$this->width` nor `$this->height` have a value other than null, then `$this->width * $this->height / 1000000;` is `0 * 0 / 1000000` which is `0`, so you're setting `$this->squares` to 0

Comment: Subsequently setting property values for `width`, `height`, `glasstype` and `color` doesn't trigger any methods to execute to recalculate.... that isn't how classes/objects work

Comment: What you could do is make those properties protected and use a magic setter that also recalculates the calculated values after any changes to those properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say, but your class is very poorly designed.

What if you had a third type of glass? Would you do this?

```
switch( $this->glasstype )
{
    case '1' :
        $this->_price['glass'] = $this->squares * 50;
        break;
    case '2' :  
        $this->_price['glass'] = $this->squares * 70;
        break;
    case '3' :  
        $this->_price['glass'] = $this->squares * 90;
        break;
}
```

What if you had 40? Would you perpetrate this `switch` nightmare?

First of all, when you name things, it should be a very descriptive name. `Price` is too generic. Since we're talking about glass price, a more suitable name would be `GlassPriceCalculator`.

Second, there is no reason at all why you should internalize the price of the square meter of glass. The way you calculate the price should be independent of the price itself. This kind of information should lie somewhere else, maybe a database.

Furthermore, there is no such thing as automatic updating a variable in PHP. Whenever you change one component of a calculated variable, you should update it.

Last thing, please, DON'T do unit transformations inside your class. Use a standardized unit of measure and stick to it.

So, you'd pobably want to rewrite your class like this:

```
class GlassTile {
    private $width;
    private $height;
    private $pricePerSquareMeter;

    public function __construct($width, $height, $pricePerSquareMeter) {
        $this->width = $width;
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->pricePerSquareMeter = $pricePerSqareMeter;
    }

    public function getArea() {
        return $this->width * $this->height;
    }

    public function getPrice() {
        return $this->getArea() * $this->pricePerSquareMeter;
    }
}

// Please, DON'T do it this way, it's just to show you the idea, but it's a very bad practice
class GlassPriceRepo {
    public static $prices = array(
        '1' => 40,
        '2' => 70,
        // ...
    );
}

class GlassPriceCalculator {
    private $tiles = array();
    public function addTile(GlassTile $tile) {
        $this->tiles[] = $tile;
    }
    public function getSumPrice() {
        return array_sum(array_map(function($tile) {
            return $tile->getPrice();
        }, $this->tiles);
    }
}
```

Using it:

```
$tile1 = new GlassTile(.8, .93, GlassPriceRepo::$prices['1']);
$tile2 = new GlassTile(.8, .93, GlassPriceRepo::$prices['2']);

$calc = new GlassPriceCalculator();

$calc->addTile($tile1);
$calc->addTile($tile2);

var_dump($calc->getSumPrice()); // yields float(81.84)
```

> Bu-but you forgot about the colors, it changes everything!

Well, in fact I didn't forget. In this case, you should use a design pattern known as [Decorator](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator). Its canonical basic structure is shown in the UML class diagram bellow:

[image: Decorator patter structure]

Bringing that to our case, you have a `GlassTile` that can be colored or not. If it is colored, it is more expensive. So, we must add this to the code above:

```
interface GlassTileInterface {
    public function getArea();
    public function getPrice();
}

class GlassTile implements GlassTileInterface {
    // ... basically the same implementation as above
}

abstract class GlassTileDecorator implements GlassTileInterface {
    protected $realTile;

    public function __construct(GlassTileInterface $tile) {
        $this->realTile = $tile;
    }

    public function getArea() {
        return $this->realTile->getArea();
    }

    public function getPrice() {
        return $this->realTile->getPrice();
    }
}

class ColoredGlassDecorator extends GlassTileDecorator {
    private $color;

    public function __construct(GlassTileInterface $tile, $color) {
        parent::__construct($tile);
        $this->color = $color;
    }

    // @override
    public function getPrice() {
        return 1.4 * parent::getPrice(); // 40% more expensive
    }
}
```

Using it:

```
$tile1 = new GlassTile(.8, .93, GlassPriceRepo::$prices['1']);
$tile2 = new ColoredGlassDecorator(new GlassTile(.8, .93, GlassPriceRepo::$prices['2']), 'blue');

$calc = new GlassPriceCalculator();

$calc->addTile($tile1);
$calc->addTile($tile2);

var_dump($calc->getSumPrice()); // yields float(102.672)
```

This way, if you need to add another type of glass, such as tempered glass, you could easily do:

```
class TemperedGlassDecorator extends GlassTileDecorator {
    private $filmThickness;

    public function __construct(GlassTileInterface $tile, $filmThickness) {
        parent::__construct($tile);
        $this->filmThickness = $filmThickness;
    }

    // @override
    public function getPrice() {
        return 2 * parent::getPrice(); // twice as expensive
    }
}
```

And then:

```
$tile1 = new TemperedGlassDecorator(
             new GlassTile(.8, .93, GlassPriceRepo::$prices['1']), 
             .002);
$tile2 = new ColoredGlassDecorator(
             new GlassTile(.8, .93, GlassPriceRepo::$prices['2']),
             'blue');
```

You could even chain decorators:

```
$anotherTile = new TemperedGlassDecorator(
                   new ColoredGlassDecorator(
                       new GlassTile(.8, .93, GlassPriceRepo::$prices['2']), 
                       'blue')
                   , .001);
```

That's all, folks!

Comment: First of all, thanks for your big answer. I really appreciate it. I am started learning OOP yesterday, so I need to learn a lot. Your answer gonna help me by learning faster. Btw I am talking about glass type and not tile. So it is the the type of glass I am using for the glass product. This is not very relevant, but maybe makes the setup a little bit different.

Comment: What are the properties of your glass types?

Comment: From your example, I could only guess that the only difference between the two types of glass was their price.

Comment: Glossy and brushed glass

Comment: Ok, but what this changes in terms of the properties? Why cannot you create `GlossyGlassDecorator` and `BrushedGlassDecorator` classes?

Answer (score 0):

The variables you set when you call the class have not been set within the class. Try:-

```
class Price{
    public $width;
    public $height;
    public $glasstype;
    public $color;
    protected $squares;
    private $_price = array();

    public function __construct($width,$height,$glasstype,$color) {

        $this->width=$width;
        $this->height=$height;
        $this->glasstype=$glasstype;
        $this->color=$color;

        $this->setSquareMeters();
        $this->glasstypePrice();    
        $this->colorPrice();
        $this->sumPrice();
    }
    protected function setSquareMeters(){
        $this->squares = ( ( $this->width * $this->height ) / 1000000 );
    }

    protected function glasstypePrice(){
        switch( $this->glasstype )
        {
            case '1' :
                $this->_price['glass'] = $this->squares * 50;
                break;
            case '2' :  
                $this->_price['glass'] = $this->squares * 70;
                break;
        }
    }

    protected function colorPrice(){
        if( $this->color != 'none' )
        {
            $this->_price['color'] = 40 * $this->squares;   
        }
    }

    protected function sumPrice(){
        $this->_price = array_sum( $this->_price ); 
    }

    public function getPrice(){
        return $this->_price;   
    }
}

$price = new Price(800,600,1,2);
echo 'Price: '.$price->getPrice();
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting property values for width, height, glasstype and color doesn't automatically trigger any methods to execute to recalculate.... that isn't how classes/objects work.

What you could do though is make those properties protected and use a "magic" setter method that also recalculates the calculated values after any changes to those properties

```
class Price
{

    protected $width;
    protected $height;
    protected $glasstype;
    protected $color;
    protected $squares;
    private $_price = array();

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->$name = $value;

        $this->setSquareMeters();
        $this->glasstypePrice();    
        $this->colorPrice();
        $this->sumPrice();
    }

    // Set millimeters to square meters 
    protected function setSquareMeters()
    {
        $this->squares = $this->width * $this->height / 1000000;
    }

    // Set glasstype price 
    protected function glasstypePrice()
    {
        switch( $this->glasstype )
        {
            case '1' :
                $this->_price['glass'] = $this->squares * 50;
                break;
            case '2' :  
                $this->_price['glass'] = $this->squares * 70;
                break;
        }
    }

    // Set color price
    protected function colorPrice()
    {
        if( $this->color != 'none' )
        {
            $this->_price['color'] = 40 * $this->squares;   
        }
    }

    // Sum price array up   
    protected function sumPrice()
    {
        return array_sum( $this->_price ); 
    }

    // Get price
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->sumPrice();   
    }

}

$price = new Price();

$price->width = 800;
$price->height = 930;
$price->glasstype = 1;
$price->color = 2;


echo $price->getPrice();
```